# No data sent in AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have code to make an AJAX request by clicking on the information checkbox. Unfortunately, the information is not sent. Does anyone know where the problem is?

```js
    $.ajax({
      url: "/addletmeknow",
      type: "Post",
      data: {
        userId: "@ViewBag.UserName",
        productId: "@ViewBag.ProductID"
      },
      //data:data,
      dataType: "json",
      //contentType: 'application/json',
      contentType: "application/json;harset=utf-8",
      success: success,
      error: Error
    })
  });
});

var Error = function(e) {
  alert("error " + e.data);
}
var success = function(e) {
  alert("success " + e);
}
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/addletmeknow", Name = "AddLetMeKnow")]
public JsonResult AddLetMeKnow(string userId, string productId) 
{
  bool res = true;
  return Json(res);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the AJAX request failing? Have you diagnose the error in the console, or stepped through the C# logic? What is the JS event you're running the code under?

Comment: Did you look at the code generated (ie view-source in the browser)?  You'll see `userId: myusername` - this should be `userId: "myusername"`.  You need to wrap `@ViewBag.UserName` in quotes (unless it already contains quotes which is *highly* unlikely).  Likely the same for ProductID.   These will be giving you errors in the console.

Comment: Saying *the information is not sent* is not helpful I'm afraid. Do you get any errors? Have you checked the browser console?

Comment: browser console :" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: When I delete the data section, it recognizes the action, but with null data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the "Response" tab of the xhr request made from your browser in the network tab of the dev tools, you will be able to see the exception details. You must be getting this exception.

> System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: userId

The reason you are getting this exception is, with your current code(even with the typo fixed), you are sending the data while specifying the `Content-Type` header value as "`application/json`" and sending the data in the request body as `userId=r&productId=34`. The Model binder present in the MVC framework will read the  value of `Content-Type` header to determine how to read the posted data and map it to your action method parameters.  The model binder want the stringified version of the data object when the content type is specified as "application/json"

You can use the `JSON.stringify` method to convr your JS object too it's stringified version.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/addletmeknow",
    type: "Post",
    data: JSON.stringify({
                             userId: "Shyju",
                             productId: "abc"
                         }),              
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: success,
    error: Error
});
```

Since this is a flat-lean view model you are sending, another option is to not specify the content type header.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/addletmeknow",
    type: "Post",
    data: {
             userId: "Shyju",
             productId: "abc"
          },              
    success: success,
    error: Error
});
```

Now jQuery ajax method will use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the `Content-Type` header value and this data will be send as FormData (`userId=r33&productId=34`) in the xhr request.